# Fonts that display in all devices and operating systems

Tags: fonts, android, mac, ios, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to know what are the Fonts which are displayed in all devices(Tablet/PC/Mac/Mobile) and platforms(iOS/Windows/Android).

The real problems is, i have designed a Powerpoint presentation with embedded fonts in Windows 7. But the fonts which i embedded are not displaying in Mac and iPad systems. Please provide me a solution for this. I want my Powerpoint be working in all devices and operating systems.

Comment: Can you add the font name for the font you're trying to embed into the question post?

Comment: The font i tried to embed in PowerPoint is 'Open Sans' and 'Walkway'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make sure you're using the right font type in PowerPoint as not all font types can be embedded.

> Note You can embed any TrueType font that is included with Microsoft
>   Windows. Other TrueType fonts can be embedded if they do not have
>   license restrictions. Other font types will not embed - [How to embed
>   fonts in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826832)

Answer (score 0):

The response to your question is:

Only "safe web fonts", e.g. Lucida, Georgia, Courrier, etc.

**Here's a list:**  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

If you use these fonts, expect some differences in your layout and don't make stuff "too precise"... as you would do for a website created in the 2000!

---

If you don't use these fonts then you need to provide the ones you used to the people who will view your Powerpoint, they will need to install them.

---

Your other option is to embed your fonts if your Powerpoint is not used only in an environment where internet is accessible or if the people who will use your Powerpoint cannot install the fonts you used.

**›** **How to embed fonts in PowerPoint :** https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826832

The restrictions and how-to are mentioned in the link above.